# Adding and deleting with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to add and delete data to the database using `ajax` and `php`.

Everything works nice. But the problem is if I delete the last item and then try to add a new one, only the first one can be added, the second one, third one... are also added to the databse, but they are not shown on the page. I can see those only when I refresh the page.

My code for delete and add :

Add :

```
<!--Dodavanje texta-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Dodavanje texta
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#btnAddText", function(e){
                var title = $("#txtTitle").val();
                var text = $("#txtText").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url : "add-text.php",
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data : {title:title, text:text},

                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#btnAddText").text("Saving...");
                    },

                    success: function(msg){
                            if(msg.br_rez == 1){
                                $(".sadrzaj").append(msg.result);
                                $("#natpisPrazno").fadeOut(300);
                                $("#txtTitle").val("");
                                $("#txtText").val("");
                                $("#btnAddText").text("Save");
                                $("#brRez").text(msg.br_rez);
                            }else{
                                $("#example1").append(msg.result);
                                $("#txtTitle").val("");
                                $("#txtText").val("");
                                $("#btnAddText").text("Save");
                                $("#brRez").text(msg.br_rez);
                            }

                    },

                    error: function(){
                        $("#error").text("Error! Something is wrong, the text is not saved!").fadeIn(300);
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Delete :

```
<!-- Brisanje texta -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //Brisanje texta
            $(document).on("click", ".btnDelText", function(){
                var cijeliID = this.id.split("-");
                var id = cijeliID[1];
                $.ajax({
                    url : "text-delete.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data : {id : id},

                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#delText-"+id).text("Deleting...");
                    }, 

                    success: function(msg){
                        if(msg){
                            if(msg == 0){
                                $(".divSadrzaj").fadeOut(300);
                                $("#natpisPrazno").addClass("alert-warning");
                                $("#natpisPrazno").fadeIn().html("Er zijn nog geen texten!");
                            }else{
                                $("#textItem-"+id).fadeOut(800);
                                $("#brRez").text(msg);  
                            }
                        }else{
                            $("#errorDel").addClass("btn-danger");
                            $("#errorDel").text("Something was wrong!");
                        }
                    },

                    error: function(){
                        $("#errorDel").addClass("btn-danger");
                        $("#errorDel").text("Something was wrong!");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And the table where the databse data is shown is :

```
<div class="content">
                <!-- Main row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 sadrzaj">
                    <?php
                        $rez = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM texts");
                        $brRez = mysqli_num_rows($rez);
                        if($brRez < 1){
                            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\" role=\"alert\" style=\"text-align:center;\">
                                    Er zijn nog geen texts!
                                  </div>"; 
                        }else{
                            echo "<div id=\"natpisPrazno\" class=\"alert\" role=\"alert\" style=\"text-align:center;\">
                                  </div>"; 
                     ?>

                         <div class="box divSadrzaj">
                            <div class="box-title">
                                <h3>Totaal texts - <span id="brRez"><b><u><?php echo $brRez; ?></u></b></span></h3>
                            </div><!-- /.box-title -->
                            <div class="box-body">
                               <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                          <th>ID</th>
                                          <th>Title</th>
                                          <th>Text</th>
                                          <th>Acties</th>  
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                        while($red = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){

                                            echo "<tr id=\"textItem-". $red["id"] ."\">
                                                    <td style=\"text-align:center;\">". $red["id"] ."</td>
                                                    <td style=\"text-align:center;\">". $red["title"] ."</td>
                                                    <td style=\"text-align:center;\">". $red["text"] ."</td>

                                                    <td style=\"text-align:center;\">
                                                        <a class=\"btn btn-danger btn-sm btnDelText\" title=\"". $red["title"] . "-wissen\" id=\"delText-". $red["id"] ."\">
                                                            <i class=\"fa fa-trash-o \"></i> 
                                                        </a>
                                                        <a class=\"btn btn-success btn-sm\" title=\"". $red["title"] . "-veranderen\" >
                                                            <i class=\"fa fa-pencil-square-o\"></i> 
                                                        </a><br/><br/>
                                                        <div id=\"errorDel\"></div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>"; 
                                        }
                                    ?>


                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                          <th>ID</th>
                                          <th>Title</th>
                                          <th>Text</th>
                                          <th>Acties</th>  
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.box -->
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div>
```

Thus everything works great if there is no data in the database and I try to add a new one, it is added to the database and shown on the page. The first one, second one..every record is added and shown. Then when I try to delete it, it works also very nice.

Only when I delete the last record, then I can add only one new record that is shown on the page. The second one is also added to the database but it is not shown on the page until I refresh the page.

Any ideas? Thanks.

***UPDATE***

When I add $(".sadrzaj") to the console I get :

[image]

When I add $(".sadrzaj").append('test'); to the cosole I get (it is shown):

[image]

When I try to add a new record, I get next response (exactly what I need to get, table row to append to the table, but it is not shown)

[image]

And then when I refresh the page I get it right :

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you to set a breakpoint in the js to add a records in the function "success". Then you can check what the variable "msg.result" contains.

Comment: I've checked it with firebug. And it containt exact what it need to contain. But it is not shown on the page.

Comment: Ok. So you are debugging the line that says "$(".sadrzaj").append(msg.result);". What happens, when you enter "$(".sadrzaj")" in the console? And what happens in the DOM when you enter "$(".sadrzaj").append('<div id="foobar">test</div>');" in the console?
Do you find the element #foobar in the dom?

Comment: I've updated my question..

Comment: Thanks for the update. You forgot to check the DOM (Tab HTML in firebug)

Comment: The first record is added, but the second one is not added. But when I click on "view page source", I see also the second record. I think that the problem is in deleting, because when I delete the last record, I do not see anything on the page, but when I click on "view page source" I see those records. I've updated my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94950/discussion-between-boky-and-lukassteiner).

Comment: @lukassteiner I solved the problem. I changed `$("#example1").append(msg.result);` to `$(".sadrzaj .divSadrzaj .box-body #example1").append(msg.result);`